# how to edit and delete each on data on group_concat() using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grouping, group-concat

I need to edit or delete each data on `GROUP_CONCAT()`. The major issue concerning me is how to pass the id of each data.

[image: Image show the data that have GROUP_CONCAT]

I need if I will add cursor to those subjects on "kiswahili" or "physics", we can expect the mouse cursor over the subject will move with link of an id of that subject on edit page or delete page.

This is my subject model code:

```
public function set_subject_get($idSchool){
    $this->db->select('standards_name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject_name SEPARATOR " || ") as subject, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id) as subjectid');
    $this->db->from('subjects');
    $this->db->join('standards', 'standards_id = subject_standard_id');
    $this->db->where('subject_school_id', $idSchool);
    $this->db->group_by('subject_standard_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

on the view page I have code like this:

```
if($subjects > 0){
    $n = 1;
    foreach($subjects as $data){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $n;?></th>
            <td><?php echo $data->standards_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->subject; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $n++;
    }
}else{
    //...
```

And the subject table contain those informations

[image: subject table]

please you can help me to move on this part thank you for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  code can be

```
$this->db->select('standards_name, GROUP_CONCAT(`subject_id`,',', subject_name ORDER BY `subject_id` SEPARATOR " || ") as subject,
```

that would look like

> ```
> SELECT 
> GROUP_CONCAT(`subject_id`,',', `subject_name` ORDER BY `subject_id` SEPARATOR " || ")
> FROM
> Options
> GROUP BY `subject_standard_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> | GROUP_CONCAT(`subject_id`,',', `subject_name` ORDER BY `subject_id` SEPARATOR " || ") |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | 1,kiswahili || 2,physies || 11,aas                                                    |
> | 3,history || 4,english || 5,geography || 6,ada || 7,ada || 8,ada || 9,s || 10,s       |
> | 17,kiswahili || 18,english || 19,history || 20,civics                                 |
> | 12,as || 13,asa || 14,asa || 15,maarifa yajamii || 16,sayansi                         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49cef3a3fbca49600d8e739ee2706ab9)*

If you want more complex, you have to loose the GROUP BY and detect the change in `subject_standard_id`

Another posibility you [split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) $data->standards_name(which i provided) first by || and then by , and have so both in separate variables, so you can buold more elaborate table structure, this has also the advantage, that you have an id for every delete or edit button

Your phpcode would look like

```
$str = '3,history || 4,english || 5,geography || 6,ada || 7,ada || 8,ada || 9,s || 10,s ';
$combine = explode("||", $str);
foreach ($combine as $tex) {
    $id_split = explode(",", trim($tex));
    echo "<a href='www.webpage.de?id=".$id_split[0]."'>".$id_split[1]."</a></br>";
}
```

And the result

```
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=3'>history</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=4'>english</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=5'>geography</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=6'>ada</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=7'>ada</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=8'>ada</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=9'>s</a></br>
<a href='www.webpage.de?id=10'>s</a></br>
```

This is of course only example how top do it.

The final result for this answer will
[image: final result]

Comment: thank you for taking your time could you please show me how to add the id on the link to the view because if you will echo $data->subjects the demonstration will id, subject || id, subject so how can you add the id on the link. You had try a lot to answer this question please you can proceed to finish this too

Comment: id of the subjects will be on $id_split[0];

Answer (score 1):

Change the sql in your Model to use **(.)** for your group concatenation.

```php
$this->db->select('standards_name, GROUP_CONCAT(`subject_id`,'.', subject_name ORDER BY `subject_id` SEPARATOR " || ") as subject,
```

So your query results will look like

```php
$subjects = [
    '1.kiswahili || 2.physies || 11.aas',
    '3.history || 4.english || 5.geography || 6.ada || 7.ada || 8.ada || 9.s || 10.s',
    '17.kiswahili || 18.english || 19.history || 20.civics',
    '12.as || 13.asa || 14.asa || 15.maarifa yajamii || 16.sayansi'
];
```

Then create a function:

```php
function subject_names_to_links($str, $url = null) {
    $domain = is_null($url) ? '/' : $url;
    $str_arr = explode('||', $str);
    $links_arr = array_map(function ($subject) use ($str_arr, $domain) {
        $subject = trim($subject);
        $subject_arr = explode('.', $subject);
        $subject_link = sprintf("<a href=%s?id=\"%s\">%s</a>", $domain, $subject_arr[0], $subject_arr[1]);
        return $subject_link;
    }, $str_arr);
    return implode(' || ', $links_arr);
}
```

Use this function into your views, to generate links.

```html
<?php foreach($subjects as $subject): ?>
    <p> <?php echo subject_names_to_links($subject); ?> </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The more you meddle with the sql in a given model method, the less likely you will be to re-use the method; so build something simple.  There is no professional / functional advantage to being tempted by the magic of sql's aggregate functions just to split what you merged in a different "layer". Keep it simple, clean, and re-usable.

If you need to order the results, do that in the model's sql.

Controller:

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($this->SubjectsModel->getSubjectsBySchoolId($schoolId) as $obj) {
    $grouped[$obj->subject_standard_id][$obj->subject_id] = $obj->subject;
}
$this->load->view('subjects', ['groupedSubjects' => $grouped]);
```

Model:

```
function getSubjectsBySchoolId(int $schoolId): array
{
    return $this->db
        ->get_where('subjects', ['subject_school_id' => $schoolId])
        ->result();
}
```

View:

```
foreach ($groupedSubjects as $standardId => $subjectsInGroup) {
    foreach ($subjectsInGroup as $id => $name) {
        echo anchor('editController/editMethod/' . $id, 'Edit ' . $name);
    }
}
```

You will need to modify the generated html to suit your table structure and link text, but this should demonstrate the vital pieces to use.

The data structure that is passed from the controller to the view is as lean as it gets.  You don't need to check if the array is empty.  The array WILL exist and the `foreach()` will only iterate if it has data to iterate.

See [CodeIgniter's manual on its `anchor()` helper method](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

I am trusting that the edit/delete clicks will load a new page AND the database will not be directly modified by the link click.  I say this because database writing actions must not be triggered by `$_GET` request, they should be delivered by `$_POST` requests.